# MongoDB replace an ObjectID reference in a document with the referenced document?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, nosql, mongodb-query

I have the following documents in two separate collections:

```
booking: {
user: ObjectID(0)
}

user: {
_id: 0
name: 'John Doe'
}
```

Is there a way to query for all booking such that in my response, `bookings[0].user` gives me the full user document instead of just the ObjectID?

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html

Comment: @dnickless I tried using lookup, but what the result I get is something like: {bookings, users}. Instead, what I want is a user to be nested inside each booking

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the following sample data:

Collection "bookings":

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a78c4517dedc1c2d1b61e3b"),
    "booking" : {
        "user" : 0
    }
}
```

Collection "users":

```
{
    "_id" : 0,
    "name" : "John Doe"
}
```

You can use [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html) like this:

```
db.getCollection('bookings').aggregate({
    $lookup: 
    {
       from: "users",
       localField: "booking.user",
       foreignField: "_id",
       as: "booking.user"
     }
})
```

This will give you the following result document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a78c4517dedc1c2d1b61e3b"),
    "booking" : {
        "user" : [ 
            {
                "_id" : 0,
                "name" : "John Doe"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Accepted answer is great, so just in case someone is wondering **how to get user as an object and not an array**, you can use $unwind stage right after:

```
db.getCollection('bookings').aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
       from: "users",
       localField: "booking.user",
       foreignField: "_id",
       as: "booking.user"
     }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$booking.user"
  }
])
```

This will result in the following document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a78c4517dedc1c2d1b61e3b"),
    "booking" : {
        "user" : {
            "_id" : 0,
            "name" : "John Doe"
        }
    }
}
```